# Is it normal that my Intel N100 server has no gpu drivers loaded on 22.04? Can i do this manually somehow

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

Hello i bought a intel n100 (cpu) nuc from china and after installing ubuntu the drivers for the gpu are not there. Is there any way to get this working on 22.04 or is it just waiting. It's a new cpu q1 2023 so maybe it just needs time. I need this for hw transcoding on plex.

Kind regards, ra

Comment: The default driver is the opensource noueau, you need to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers yourself.  Still problems, then for a new NUC, try Ubuntu 23.04 with a later kernel.

Comment: updating to 22.10 and then checking drivers with lshw got me the i915 driver showing. This worked! Now my plex can hw transcode. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 is nearing EOL, so better update to 23.04 soon.  You may answer your own question and accept it (maybe after a few days), helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating to 22.10 and then checking drivers with lshw got me the i915 driver showing. This worked! Now my plex can hw transcode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The latest `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04` is `6.2.0.26.26~22.04.7` (i.e. Linux Kernel 6.2), and now it supports Intel N100's UHD Graphics:

```
$ sudo lshw | grep i915
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
$ sudo lspci -v | grep i915
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```